# jquery remove class no me funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo una [pagina](https://github.com/PySanti/U-Information) (el archivo index esta en `pagina/html/html_initial_page`), y quiero que el `sidebar` se cierre cuando se le de `click` al `close_btn`, el caso es que dentro del JS para el `sidebar` ...

```
"use strict";
const sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0];
const eventual_class_name = "sidebar_desplieged";
const sideBarElementsContainerClassName = "sidebar_elements_container"
let close_btn = null;
const closeBtnClassName = "close__btn";

function getCloseButton() {
    let sideBarElementsContainer = null;
    for (let child of sidebar.children){
        if (child.classList.contains(sideBarElementsContainerClassName)){
            sideBarElementsContainer = child;
            for (let element of sideBarElementsContainer.children){
                if(element.classList.contains(closeBtnClassName)){
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

close_btn = getCloseButton();

console.log(close_btn);

sidebar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!sidebar.classList.contains(eventual_class_name)) 
        sidebar.classList.add(eventual_class_name);
});

close_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sidebar.classList.remove(eventual_class_name);
})
```

Por alguna razon esto solo ocurre en el bloque del `eventListener` de `close_btn`, a lo que me refiero es que literalmente copio y pego la misma linea en el bloque del `eventListener` del `sidebar` y si funciona. Ya logre arreglarlo, simplemente aplique estilos de otro modo (sin usar clases), sin embargo ahora mi pregunta es: *por que paso esto?*

Comment: Y si usas mejor removeClass

Comment: Fijate en el Linkeado del JS ponele defer, o asigna los event en un onload o un onready para estar seguro que econtro el boton.

Comment: De entrada, ya veo un problema tipográfico que podría estar relacionado. Al condicional del event listener que añade la clase, le faltan las llaves:

`sidebar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!sidebar.classList.contains(eventual_class_name)) {
    sidebar.classList.add(eventual_class_name);
  }
});`

Pero la verdad es que creo que no es lo único que puede fallar. También deberías comprobar que la clase existe antes de intentar quitarla con el close btn. 

No he comprobado más cosas porque no has montado un fiddle fácilmente manipulable, pero es posible que haya más errores.

Comment: El acceso a los elementos no es el problema, ya lo comprobe ...

Comment: @FacundoE.Villagra que es un defer? (soy bastante novato en js aun)

Comment: cuando cargas la etiqueta script le agregas defer de esta forma <script defer src="archiv.js">, eso hace que solo se ejecute al terminar de cargar el HTML completo.

Answer (score 0):

Usa

```
removeClass('clase_a_remover')
```

esto remueve completamente la clase o también en este caso podrías usar

```
removeAttr('class')
```

eliminaras el atributo clase completamente del elemento y después podrías crearla como la necesites nuevamente

```
attr('class','clase_como_la_necesitas_despues_de_quitarla')
```